# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python-3.x

всем доброго времени суток. Просьба помочь разобраться с ошибкой. Из sql скрипт брал две переменные, айди группы и интервал, текст был прописал в самом скрипте. Решил перенести text в sql но при этом выдает указанную ошибку. Если что я только учусь поэтому строго не судите пожалуйста, а разжуйте нубу что делаю не так и как надо. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

```
 

        list_of_groups = []
        a = []
        text = []
        connection = sqlite3.connect("stats.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE chats(
            id INTEGER,
            time TEXT
            text TEXT)
        ''')
        connection.commit()
    except:
        pass

    @app.on_message(filters.command("time", prefixes="/") & filters.me)
    async def time(_, msg: Message):
        global text
        global connection
        global list_of_groups
        global cursor
        text = cursor.execute("SELECT text FROM chats WHERE id=?", (msg.chat.id,)).fetchone()
        check = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chats").fetchall()
        done_list = str(check).replace(", '", "/").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(",", "").replace("'",
                                                                                                              "").replace(
            "[", "").replace("]", "").split()
        list_of_groups = done_list
        start, end = map(str, msg.text.replace("/time ", "").split())
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        used = []
        while True: #
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            if str(now)[11:16] == start:
                for group in list_of_groups:
                    nud, interval, text = map(str, group.replace("/", " ").split())е
                    try:
                        await app.send_message(chat_id=int(nud), text=text)
```